# Async Recursive File System Traversal

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to compile an array out of data present in some specific files, using a recursive approach to read directories and the file system methods are asynchronous. I am unable to figure out the apt place for the callback invocation.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ENTRY =  "../a/b";
const FILE_NAME = 'index.json';
var nodes = [];

function doThisOnceDone() {
    console.log(nodes);
}

function readFile(path) {
    fs.readFile(path + '/' + FILE_NAME,{
        encoding:"UTF-8"
    }, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            return;
        }
        nodes.push(data);
    });
}
function compileArray(path, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, {
        encoding:"UTF-8"
    }, function(err, files) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            var nextPath = path + '/' + file;
            fs.stat(nextPath, function(err, stats) {
                if(err) {
                    return;
                }
                if(stats.isDirectory()) {
                    if(file === 'specific') {
                        readFile(nextPath);
                    }
                    else {
                        compileArray(nextPath);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

compileArray(ENTRY, doThisOnceDone);
```

When do I know that the recursion tree has been done with , and I can access the nodes array ?

Comment: use async await with Util.promisify.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

const ENTRY = "../a/b";
const FILE_NAME = 'index.json';
var nodes = [];

const compileArray = async (path) => {
    try {
        const files = await readdir(path);
        files.forEach((file) => {
            try {
                var nextPath = path + '/' + file;
                const stats = await stat(nextPath); //check other conditions
                if (file === 'specific') {
                    const data = await readFile(path + '/' + FILE_NAME, {
                        encoding: "UTF-8"
                    });
                    nodes.push(data);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: breaks  at  const stats = await stat(nextPath); SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Thanks though , I am trying to understand what you've put up.

Comment: const stats = await stat(nextPath);  is not essentially within an async function , so breaks I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const util = require('util');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
    const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

    const ENTRY = "../a/b";
    const FILE_NAME = 'index.json';
    var nodes = [];

    const compileArray = async (path) => {
        try {
            const files = await readdir(path);
            files.forEach(async (file) => {
                try {
                    var nextPath = path + '/' + file;
                    const stats = await stat(nextPath); //check other conditions
                    if (file === 'specific') {
                        const data = await readFile(path + '/' + FILE_NAME, {
                            encoding: "UTF-8"
                        });
                        nodes.push(data);
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

compileArray(ENTRY)
```

Comment: await can be used within an async function only.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out , where do I access the nodes array once the recursion is complete.